# Convert multitype series containing rows of hex to ascii

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe like below:

```
  type     value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  hex      "6d,79,20,6e,61,6d,65,20,69,73,20,6a,6f,68,6e,0a"                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  name     john                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  dynamic  12                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  action   encroach                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  hex_2    "4d,69,6e,65,20,69,73,20,73,61,75,6c,2c,20,6e,69,63,65,20,74,6f,20,6d,65,65,74,20,79,6f,75,2e,20"                                                                                                                                                    
  hex      "4d,79,20,6e,61,6d,65,20,69,73,20,4d,61,74,74"                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  name     Matt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  dynamic  91                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  action   penalty                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  hex_2   "49,20,61,6d,20,61,6e,20,65,6e,63,6f,64,65,64,20,6d,65,73,73,61,67,65,20,74,68,61,74,20,49,20,68,61,76,65,20,74,6f,20,6b,65,65,70,20,69,6e,74,65,72,6e,61,6c,20,74,6f,20,6d,79,20,6f,72,67,61,6e,69,7a,61,74,69,6f,6e,2e,20"
```

How can I conditionally reformat the hex and hex_2 to ascii?

Current code is as follows to convert hex to ascii with function call:

```
def ascii_convert(char):
    value = int(char, 16)
    if 32 <= value < 128:
        return chr(value)
    else:
        return char

Current Failed attempt at converting:
print(df[df['type'].str.contains('hex|hex_2').apply(lambda x: ascii_convert(x)))
```

Expected Output:

```
  type     value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  hex      my name is john      # converted                                                                                                                                                                                             
  name     john                 # Untouched                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  dynamic  12                   # Untouched                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  action   encroach             # Untouched                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  hex_2    Mine is saul, nice to meet you.  # converted                                                                                                                                             
  hex      My name is Matt      # converted                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  name     Matt                 # Untouched                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  dynamic  91                   # Untouched                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  action   penalty              # Untouched                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  hex_2    I am an encoded message that I have to keep internal to my organization.   # converted
```

I know the conversion function works for the characters but am having trouble using the function within my specific criteria. My data type labels can have 5 or six different labels I would like to convert from hex to ascii such as the hex and hex_2.

Any help would be amazing. thank you.

Comment: so you have columns hex, hex1, hex2, hex3, hex4, hex5, which you would like to convert?

Comment: for completeness can you post a sample of your data

Comment: so you want to reformat the hex and hex_2 columns if the value column is some value? roughly `reformat(x) if x.value == 'some_value' `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had some error handling and issues with the data. This ending up assiting with the removal of the null bytes and error handling from all my files if they didnt contain the proper data requirements.

```
def fn(foo):
    if "NONE" in foo:
        return foo
    else:
        try:
            x = foo.replace(' ', '')
            x = foo.replace('00', '')
            return "".join(binascii.unhexlify(x).decode())
        except:
            binascii.Error

df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.split(',')
df['Value'] = df[df['Type'].str.contains('hex')]['Value'].apply(lambda x: fn("".join(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The attempt is failing because with `str.contains('hex|hex_2')` you're trying to match the exact string 'hex|hex_2'. but no columns exist with that name.

Instead, since you confirmed that all the columns you want to convert have the string 'hex' in the name this should do.

```
 data["value"] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_ascii(x["value"]) \
 if 'hex' in x["type"] else x["value"], axis=1)
```

This selects the values of rows with 'hex' in `type` column and converts them, leaving the others columns untouched

**here is an example:**

```
  one  two labels
0  70  1      o
1  67  0      b
2  57  1      o
3  64  1      b
4  74  0      o
5  65  1      b
6  56  1      o
7  59  1      b
8  60  1      o
9  63  0      b
```

apply function and update the labels column:

```
data["type"] = data.apply(lambda x: x["labels"] *4 \
               if x["one"] >= 60 else x["labels"], axis=1)

   one  two labels
0   70    1   oooo
1   67    0   bbbb
2   57    1      o
3   64    1   bbbb
4   74    0   oooo
5   65    1   bbbb
6   56    1      o
7   59    1      b
8   60    1   oooo
9   63    0   bbbb
```

Comment: Is this attempting to convert the type column that contains the string "hex" to ascii value with my function? I have about 20 columns and only want to convert the df.Value column if it contains the corresponding df.type.str.contains('hex').

Comment: @johnnyb see if this helps

Comment: @johnnyb see example